# Is there any way to detect if the Canvas Profiler is Enabled via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, profiler, createjs

Is there any way to run a Chrome-specific detection to see if the Canvas Profiler is currently enabled (ex: `console['isCanvasProfilerEnabled']`)?

The reason why I ask is because I occasionally forget it is active, and when I go to profile / debug a game made in *CreateJS*, any **masked objects** are completely invisible (*causes a lot of frustration / wasted time*).

At least if some form of run-time detection exists, I could set a `console.log(...)` or `throw` an exception when masks are encountered in the scene's display-list.

**EDIT:** Here's a screenshot of the option I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: I cannot even activate  the feature in chrome 51.
(activated experimental devtools features, but it is not showing up in settings)